# Excel 2007 VBA Code to Copy Row from Worksheet 1 to Worksheet 2 if single criteria met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet ('CSVin') containing rows of sales order data (from row 2 to row 101). If the 'quantity' column (column 'C') is greater than 0, I want to copy the whole row to another worksheet ('CSVout'), starting at row 2. Therefore, there are 100 rows of data in CSVin, but (for example) there may only be 12 rows that have a 'quantity' greater than 0, and these 12 rows need to be copied to CSVout.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have looked at lots of pieces of code for this, but they don't match my need and I don't seem to be able to modify them correctly as I don't have a lot of VBA experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need code such as the below. Please review and let me know if you can incorporate it into your worksheet:

```
Sub SendToSheet2()
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rngToCopy As Range

    Set wsIn = Worksheets("CSVin")
    Set wsOut = Worksheets("CSVOut")
    Set rngToCopy = wsIn.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    wsOut.Cells.ClearContents

    rngToCopy.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"

    rngToCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsOut.Range("A1")

    wsIn.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```